# Finding unique solution puzzle python

Tags: python, python-2.7, puzzle, sliding-tile-puzzle

```
x = np.array([[0,1,11],[0,2,11],[0,3,10],[0,4,10],[0,5,9],[0,6,9],[1,7,9],
              [1,5,11],[1,6,11],[2,7,11],[2,8,10]])
```

I'm pretty new to this so i'm gonna call things like this [element1,element2,element3]

i have an array as shown above, and i want to find a solution to this array.
It should satisfy the following conditions:

The first element 0:

it should have atleast one solution from `[0,1,11],[0,2,11],[0,3,10],[0,4,10],[0,5,9],[0,6,9]`

The first element 1:

this : `[1,7,9],[1,5,11],[1,6,11]`

The first element 2:

and this : `[2,7,11],[2,8,10]`

Such that the second element and 3rd element is unique for each solution(where 1st element=0,second element=1 and 3rd element=2)

o/p can be :
`[0,1,11]` and `[1,7,9]` and `[2,8,10]`

wrong output : 
`[0,1,11], [1,6,11] ,[2,8,10]`
here parameter 3 of the first and the second are same.

Comment: which part of it do you want me to elaborate

Comment: what are the parameters?

Comment: Write code.  Show it to us.

Comment: okay to elaborating more:

Comment: @ArohiGupta is this puzzle maybe available online somewhere? If so, could you please, please link to it? This is simply incomprehensible as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to produce triplets from the given `x` array so that the first, second and third element are all unique in one triplet. Code to do that:

```
import itertools

x = [[0,1,11],[0,2,11],[0,3,10],[0,4,10],[0,5,9],[0,6,9],[1,7,9],
              [1,5,11],[1,6,11],[2,7,11],[2,8,10]]
triplets = itertools.combinations(x,3)
for t in triplets:
  isGood = True
  for pos in range(3):
    if (t[0][pos] == t[1][pos] or t[0][pos] == t[2][pos] or t[1][pos] == t[2][pos]):
      isGood = False
  if (isGood):
    print(repr(t))
```

This procudes the following output:

```
([0, 1, 11], [1, 7, 9], [2, 8, 10])
([0, 2, 11], [1, 7, 9], [2, 8, 10])
([0, 5, 9], [1, 6, 11], [2, 8, 10])
([0, 6, 9], [1, 5, 11], [2, 8, 10])
```

---

A more pythonic solution which does the same in only 3 lines

```
for t in itertools.combinations(x,3):
  if all(len(col) == len(set(col)) for col in zip(*t)):
    print(repr(t))
```

---

Insane one-liner:

```
print(''.join(repr(t) + '\n' for t in itertools.combinations(x,3) if all(len(col) == len(set(col)) for col in zip(*t))))
```

Comment: can you please tell me the algo.